# Jquery: calculate sum of all table rows select/text box value and last column value

Tags: jquery

#### I want to achieve what has shown in this image

[image: I want to achieve what has shown in this image]

1. Calculate total in front of every row's Total.
2. Calculate Invoice Amount which is nothing but sum of All total Boxes.
3. Group tax amount based on the Tax selected in each row.
4. When delete a row all boxes should get updated.

I tried to do with each and every element ID but it does not update respective Total box values unless and until I do not focus that field again. also when I delete a in-between row then again I need trigger an event on which function is getting call. I tried with

```
 sumjq = function(selector) {
 var sum = 0;
 $(selector).each(function() {
    sum += Number($(this).text());
});
return sum;
}
```

[Here is my jsFiddle (updated)](https://jsfiddle.net/gourshivam/80yx1w5e/4/)

Comment: There's no JS in you Fiddle.

Comment: Its written here in question.

Comment: jsFiddle is updated